# VBA attachment naming script opens two replies

Tags: vba, email, outlook, email-attachments, reply

I have a script which I use to list attachments in an email I am replying to. It has been working fine for a few days since I last adjusted it but today it has started opening an extra reply window when it reaches the `End Sub` line. I’ve tried resetting it to how it was last week but it still does it. I presume it’s just an option which I have accidentally switched on.

```
' Reply
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim FinalMsg As String
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olDocument As Word.Document
Dim olSelection As Word.Selection

If bDiscardEvents Or oItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
       Exit Sub
End If

'Cancel = True
bDiscardEvents = True
strAtt = ""

Dim AttNam As String
FinalMsg = ""
For Each oAtt In oItem.Attachments
AttNam = LCase(oAtt.FileName)
    If oAtt.Size > 5200 Then
        strAtt = strAtt & "<" & oAtt.FileName & ">, "
    End If
Next oAtt

If strAtt = "" Then Exit Sub
FinalMsg = "Attached" & ": " & strAtt

    Set oResponse = oItem.Reply
    oResponse.Display

    Set olInspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set olDocument = olInspector.WordEditor
    Set olSelection = olDocument.Application.Selection

 'Find the end of the signature
With ActiveInspector.WordEditor.Application
    .Selection.WholeStory
    .Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With .Selection.Find
        .Text = "Subject:"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Execute
    End With

    Dim SubjectFont As String 'capture formatting details to allow blending
    Dim SubjectSize As Integer
    SubjectFont = .Selection.Font.Name
    SubjectSize = .Selection.Font.Size

    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    .Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    If InStr(.Selection.Text, "mportance") <> 0 Then
    .Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove
    End If

End With

olSelection.InsertBefore FinalMsg


bDiscardEvents = False
Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by commenting out `Cancel = True` which presumably cancels the original procedure. Re-enabling this causes the script to only open the reply opened by `oResponse.Display`